# I need to send tokens from my eth address with 0 gas fee

Tags: erc-20

I need to send tokens from my eth address with 0 gas fee.On my address has script autobot which automatically sends ether to self or on other address after getting within 1-2 minutes,sometimes 3-7 minutes.
Hope you offer how to decide.Also I see that some people may send any tokens or ether with absolutely 0 fee,I see that on some transactions

Comment: This is not possible from an externally owned account, unless you are mining your own blocks.

Comment: Hey do you have a link to those 0 fee transactions ? I'm quite curious. A fee always need to be paid, wether you're submitting it or someone else on your behalf.

Comment: Whoever mined the tx in your example is likely in control of the receiver address. If you are mining your own blocks, you can mine a tx with a 0 gas price.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily *need* to be paid. You can create a tx with a 0 gwei gas fee, it's just that miners aren't likely to mine them since they're not getting anything out of it.

Answer (score 3):

> Also I see that some people may send any tokens or ether with absolutely 0 fee,I see that on some transactions

As @flygoing mentioned in the comment to one of the other answers (which should really be comments), you can submit your transactions with any gas price you like, including a gas price of 0.

However, gas prices form a market, and if there are any other transactions currently in the transaction pool with non-zero prices, then those transactions are almost certainly going to be mined first.

A second consideration was mentioned by @RaghavSood, in that a miner might be putting his own transactions into a block he himself is mining.

Finally, there could be further, more complex reasons why a miner would include a zero-fee transaction. For example, if a miner wanted to create the fullest block possible<sup>1</sup>, and there were no further fee-paying transactions in the pool - or at least any transactions of an appropriate size - then it might be advantageous to include zero-priced transactions (of an appropriate size). In the case you've pointed to, the block was 99.80% full.

> I need to send tokens from my eth address with 0 gas fee

You're either going to need to be lucky, or mine your own blocks.

---

<sup>1</sup> Depending on the miner's mining strategy, they might want to do this to influence the speed at which the block can both propagate around the network and be validated by other miners.

Answer (score 0):

The solution: 
*A contract that generates other contracts that act as receivers.*

Now when you want to create a wallet that receives ERC20 tokens, but do not want to seed each wallet yourself, you can deploy a receiver contract from the main wallet that acts as a centralized gas pool.

**Relevant Stackexchange Answer:** [Common Gas Wallet for ERC20 Wallets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76016/common-gas-pool-for-erc20-wallets/76158#76158)

**Relevant Github Link:**
https://github.com/Meshugah/ERC20-CommonGasWallet